# How draw a putpixel in python?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to draw a pixel, this is my function, i want create a function to put a pixel

```
class Pixel(QPainter):
    def putPixel(self, x,y, value):
        self.begin(self)
        self.drawPoint(QPoint(x, y))
        self.end()
```

i am using, that function

```
        qp = QPainter()
        pixel = Pixel(qp)
        pixel.putPixel(100, 100,1)
```

what is the problem? i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPainter(): too many arguments
  QPainter(QPaintDevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPainter'
```

Comment: QPainter is a class that is used to paint some decice (QImage, QPixmap, QWidget, etc) so my question is, on what device do you want to paint?

Comment: @eyllanesc i want to paint in QWidget

Comment: I also have other questions: are you sure that this code generates that error? I'm pointing this out because putPixel doesn't have the "self" argument. Another thing is what does "value" mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc value its the color, and self argument i dont know, when i put the seft i get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QPainter is a painter class, that is, it has the task of painting some QPaintDevice such as QPixmap, QImage, QWidget, etc. But in your code when using "self.begin(self)" you are indicating that the QPainter is going to paint itself and that has no logic. On the other hand you don't use value at all which is also inconsistent.

The correct logic is that before calling putPixel the device must be set:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class PixelPainter(QPainter):
    def putPixel(self, x, y, value):
        self.save()
        pen = QPen(QColor(value))
        pen.setWidth(1)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.drawPoint(QPoint(x, y))
        self.restore()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = PixelPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        for x in range(200):
            painter.putPixel(x, x, QColor("red"))
        painter.end()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why do you use save and restore?

Comment: @hubman The save() and restore methods save and restore the state of the QPainter, respectively. In this case for example if the painter has a previous pen then with putPixel you can change it so to avoid that problem I restore it. Please read the Qt docs

Comment: i want to use in other class:  class Line():
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = PixelPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
i am getting this error TypeError: begin(self, QPaintDevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Line'

Comment: @hubman  From my answer: *it has the task of painting some QPaintDevice such as QPixmap, QImage, QWidget, etc*,  And I ask you, is Line a QPaintDevice? I recommend you review the concepts of OOP, especially the concept of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

you can modify this part

```
def putPixel(self,x,y, value):
        self.save()
        self.drawPoint(QPoint(x, y))
        self.restore()
```